# PHP project Vagrant setup error [NodeJs installation step]

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, virtualbox, symlink

I'm doing setup of my PHP project using vagrant on virtualbox on WINDOWS 10,On command line When I hit

`vagrant up`

Setup begins, During setup At this step

```
==> default: TASK [app : Angular - Install dependencies]
```

I'm getting this error

```
        ==> default: TASK [app : Angular - Install dependencies] ************************************
    ==> default: fatal: [10.91.0.102]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "npm install", "delta": "0:06:23.111672", "end": "2017-10-05 05:46:47.136976", 
    "failed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 185, "start": "2017-10-05 05:40:24.025304", "stderr": "npm WARN deprecated typings@2.1.1: 
    Typings is deprecated in favor of NPM @types -- see README for more information\nnpm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue\nnpm WARN optional
     SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):\nnpm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {\"os\":\"darwin\",\"arch\":\"any\"} 
     (current: {\"os\":\"linux\",\"arch\":\"x64\"})\nnpm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=4.3.0
     but none was installed.\nnpm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=4.3.0 but none was installed.\nnpm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=4.3.0
     but none was installed.\nnpm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/forms@>=4.3.0 but none was installed.\nnpm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of rxjs@>=5.4.3 
     but none was installed.\nnpm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 but none was installed.\nnpm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-132-generic\nnpm ERR! argv \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/usr/local/bin/npm\" 
     \"install\"\nnpm ERR! node v7.0.0\nnpm ERR! npm  v3.10.8\nnpm ERR! path ../typescript/bin/tsserver\nnpm ERR! code EPROTO\nnpm ERR! errno -71\nnpm ERR! syscall symlink\n\nnpm 
     ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../typescript/bin/tsserver' -> '/vagrant/angular_admin/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/.bin/tsserver'\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! If you need help,
     you may report this error at:\nnpm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>\n\nnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:\nnpm ERR!    
     /vagrant/angular_admin/npm-debug.log", "stderr_lines": ["npm WARN deprecated typings@2.1.1: Typings is deprecated in favor of NPM @types -- see README for more information", "npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: 
     Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue", "npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):", 
     "npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {\"os\":\"darwin\",\"arch\":\"any\"} (current: {\"os\":\"linux\",\"arch\":\"x64\"})", "npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 
     requires a peer of @angular/common@>=4.3.0 but none was installed.", "npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=4.3.0 but none was installed.", "npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 
     requires a peer of @angular/core@>=4.3.0 but none was installed.", "npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of @angular/forms@>=4.3.0 but none was installed.", "npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6
     requires a peer of rxjs@>=5.4.3 but none was installed.", "npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 but none was installed.", "npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-132-generic", 
     "npm ERR! argv \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/usr/local/bin/npm\" \"install\"", "npm ERR! node v7.0.0", "npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8", "npm ERR! path ../typescript/bin/tsserver", "npm ERR! code EPROTO", "npm ERR! errno -71",
     "npm ERR! syscall symlink", "", "npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../typescript/bin/tsserver' -> '/vagrant/angular_admin/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/.bin/tsserver'", "npm ERR! ",
     "npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:", "npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>", "", "npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:", "npm ERR!    
     /vagrant/angular_admin/npm-debug.log"], "stdout": "angular_admin@2.0.1 /vagrant/angular_admin\n├── @angular/animations@4.0.3 \n├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.0.3\n├── UNMET PEER DEPENDE
```

Error is so long, so I just copied beginning part of it.

Now its showing this error http://mysticpaste.com/3OP1NJG73p

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The error message is about the NodeJS packages problem, not PHP (-;

Comment: @Neodan Yes it is NodeJS package issue, how can I resolve it ?

Comment: don't forget to mark an answer or add your answer, if the right answer wasn't provided. In other way this question will be useless in future.

Comment: @Neodan I'm still getting the same error, no success yet..!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that you can't use symlinks.

You have a few options:

- Try to add `--no-bin-links` flag to `npm install` commands or  set it
  in in global configuration as default (`npm config set bin-links
  false`).
- If you running Vagrant on top of Windows, try to run
  `vagrant up` as addministrator.

If you do not want to run VirtualBox as administrator, you can allow creating symlinks for all users:

- Open the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Edit the `Create symbolic links` policy at: Computer configuration → Windows Settings → Security Settings → Local 
  Policies → User Rights Assignment → Create symbolic links

Comment: I have added --no-bin-links flag to npm install command, Now long error is not showing but its showing this error http://mysticpaste.com/3OP1NJG73p

Comment: Looks like that the problem is caused by too much recursive call inside the script. Try to take a look there: github.com/npm/npm/issues/9953